# I have enabled keep-alive but it isn't working

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, server, keep-alive

I have enabled the keep-alive option in my WHM

but I still get "close" when I have checked by many tools like this

http://www.giftofspeed.com/check-keep-alive/

http://gtmetrix.com/

And I have added the code in .htaccess file but the option is still not working

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
```

And when I create php file to print "HTTP_CONNECTION"

I get "close"

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have to reconfigure `apache` to have it handle `keepalive`.

The most relevant settings are:

```
KeepAlive            On
Keepalivetimeout     5
MaxKeepaliveRequests 100
```

See the documentation here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#keepalive

And a discussion which points to some caveats here:

https://abdussamad.com/archives/169-Apache-optimization:-KeepAlive-On-or-Off.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, But I have configured my apache configuration as your code, But It isn't working

Comment: What did you do? How did you test?

Comment: I'm used these tools and I'm used php line to display the connection type

http://www.giftofspeed.com/check-keep-alive/

http://gtmetrix.com/

Comment: Where did you put the statements above? Vhost configuration? Main one? Did you check, if there is a "KeepAlive Off" somewhere else?

Comment: Firstly, I'm used the editor of whm for apache configuration.
After that, I'm used an editor for httpd.conf file

Comment: The question is: are there any more `Keepalive` directives in your config, possibly taking precedence over you entries.

Comment: I have searched about any keepalive in the file and I didn't found any other, And I have checked if the directive in IF condition or not

Comment: Can you show the output of a `wget` to the server with ` --save-headers`?